# How to get height of triangle by midpoint

Tags: math

I have midpoint of triangle and also i don't other vertex information So how will i calculate height of triangle with mid-point formula?

sorry i m editing it.although this is math problem but i am making computer program.I had vertex information this is being lost in program execution so i m keeping only midpoint.So in flow of program i have only midpoint information.So how will i calculate height of triangle if i have triangle vertex like (-0.5,0), (0.5,0),(0.0,1).

Comment: Huh? If all you have is a point, there is no triangle.

Comment: there are infinitely many rectangles with the same midpoint.  They will have different heights.  Your question is incomplete or doesn't have an answer.

Comment: Plz see question again i have edited it.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*If you do have all three vertices*, then the "height" is still not well defined. Each of the three vertices has a "height" from  the corresponding opposite side. In general, these are not equal.

To get the distance of a given vertex `c` from the opposite side (a,b) use cross products:

Define

```
a = (ax, ay)
b = (bx, by)
c = (cx, cy)
```

Compute:

```
bMinusA == b-a  == (bMinusAx, bMinusAy)
                 = (bx - ax, by - ay)
cMinusA == c-a  == (cMinusAx, cMinusAy)
                 = (cx - ax, cy - ay)
```

Compute:

```
bMinusCcrossCMinusA == |(b-a)^(c-a)| 
                   = abs(bMinusAx* cMinusAy - bMinusAy*cMinusAx)
```

Then:

```
  heightCfromAB = bMinusCcrossCMinusA/ length(bMinusA)
                = bMinusCrosscMinusA/ sqrt( bMinusAx*bMinusAx+  bMinusAy* bMinusAy)
```

Note that if you permute the vertices, you always get the same for the cross-product ( bar a sign), as it is twice the area of the triangle.

The heights then vary inversely with the length of the opposite side.

So if you like, you can find the greatest height by first finding the shortest side and using that.

**Correction**: Original expression for cross product **had a typo**. Corrected.

Comment: Thanks, this has been hugely useful. Although I'm still not certain where does definition of cross product in two dimensions come from... I think that's not cross product _per se_, but something similar in two dims, although I can't seem to find a definition...

Comment: @kralyk. Weirdly, most of the technical material is there to support higher dimensions, but it does work for two. At its simplest level, you can think of the cross product of the 2D vectors as being two vectors in the XY sub-plane of 3D space.. The result is in the z-direction. I.e. The 2D cross product is just the same as what you'd compute as the z-component in a 3D cross product. The cross product in (flat) three dimensional geometry is just a special case of what is known as an outer or exterior product (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra ).

Comment: @kralyk. Reread this and noticed a major error - no wonder you could not find that "definition" of the cross product! Corrected.